# Redirecting the data from TCP IP to /dev/tty*--but no physical device is connected

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, gpsd

On the client side,there is a  gpsd process that takes GPS data from physical device port /dev/tty and expects the device to be connected to client.

But my case is different, I am getting the GPS data over an IP 192.168.0.61 and 10002 port and device is connected to server. I can connect to it using telnet 192.168.0.61 10002. I cannot access the server side of it, so cannot run any other process other than to accept the data from TCP IP.

I am wondering if any one of you can tell me how I can get the GPSD to take the data from TCP IP port .

May be a way to redirect the TCP IP data on to a /dev/tty.

One problem is I dont have the device connected on client side so, there wont be any /dev/tty.

Comment: Are you sure the process gets its input from `/dev/tty` and not standard input? That seems like a very unusual way for a program to work. /dev/tty is almost always used just to communicate with the end user, not random devices.

Comment: Generally the program expects the device to be connected to Client. But in my case I am getting data on TCP IP...

Comment: /dev/tty is the user's terminal, not a client.

Comment: Is there a link to the documentation of the gpsd program?

Comment: I edited the question if I was not clear previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gpsd can use a TCP connection. See this in the gpsd(8) man page:

> TCP feed
>
> A URI with the prefix "tcp://", followed by a hostname, a
> colon, and a port number. The daemon will open a socket to the
> indicated address and port and read data packets from it, which will
> be interpreted as though they had been issued by a serial device.
> Example: tcp://data.aishub.net:4006.

Comment: Thank you so much..It worked and it reminds me how negligent i was in reading the doc...But thank you for your support